React recommendation against how many services a component can use
We have a component like EditProductForm.tsx but to edit a product we need to load this product by id, and handle the validations and submit process. To write these logic we usually creates services which are hooks:
// useLoadProductService.ts
export default function useLoadProductService({productId}):{ productForm } {

  function loadTheProduct() : productForm {
    // load the product
  }
  return {
    productForm: loadTheProduct()
  }
}

// useHandleProductEditService.ts
export default function useHandleProductEditService({form}):{  } {

  function submitClick() {
    // store the form
  }
  
  return {
    submitClick: submitClick,
  }
}


// EditProductForm.tsx
export default function EditProductForm({productId}): ReactNode {
  const {productForm} = useLoadProductService({productId});
  const service = useHandleProductEditService({form: productForm});

  return (
    <form>
      <input ... />
    </form>
  );
}

In our component we use two services. The topic is: is it not recommended for a component to use more than one service at a time? What is the problem when write components like this one? What is the advantage of using only one service?
The recommendation is use one. To achieve this, there are two different way:

the useHandleProductEditService contains all the code which now are separated in useLoadProductService, which (for me) has no advantage at all
the useHandleProductEditService inside it uses the useLoadProductService, and what it returns, it also returns. In this case the useHandleProductEditService have all the properties it needs, and also the ones for the useHandleProductEditService, and pass them to it. This super-service in this case also seems not too much advantage for me.

Is it some advantage of using only one service, and face all the problems and challenges by creating this giant and complex services against writing and using smaller ones? Why it is recommended?

This is a opinion-based question and there is no absolute correct answer.
My opinion: There is no limit to use multiple hooks in a react component. The service, hook, component etc... They are just JS function, so the general design principle of functions are:

Single-responsibility principle

Separation of concerns

Don't repeat yourself

Duplication is far cheaper than the wrong abstraction

Single Level of Abstraction Principle


After clarifying their functions, design hooks and components based on actual demands.
The goal of following the above principles is to improve the readability, maintainability, reusability and scalability of the code.

Yeah, the suggested solution is against the SOLID principles. The question is "is there something I don't know about react why is it anti-pattern to use multiple services for the same component" ...

@ZoltanHernyak I never heard use multiple services in a single component is a anti-pattern.

@ZoltanHernyak "is there something I don't know about react why is it anti-pattern to use multiple services for the same component" - According to whom? Who is making this claim?

@DrewReese does not really matters, he is my lead developer... I'm just waiting for some real reason not like that "its a recommendation" - without knowing why it is recommended :)

@ZoltanHernyak Obviously don't go overboard, but use as many hooks as is necessary to implement the required business logic. 0, 1, 5, maybe 10 hooks is not bad, but 20, 30, 50, yeah, probably time to refactor and abstract them a bit. Keep in mind that React hooks can call other React hooks, so group logical units of code together where you can.
